# Graph Theory: Connectivity and Path

Tags: graph-theory

For an undirected network with $n$ vertices, the maximum possible length of a walk from vertex $i$ to $j$ with each intermediate vertex visited once only is $n-1$.

If $A_{ij} = (A^{2})_{ij} = \cdots = (A^{n-1})_{ij} = 0$ where $A$ is the adjacency matrix, it seems to suggest that vertex $i$ and $j$ cannot be reached from each other. But how can I prove or disprove this statement?

Comment: Do you need a proof of your first statement or a proof that $(A^k)_{ij}$ is the number of walks of length $k$ from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$? Once you have those two statements, your proof is done.

Comment: @DannyRorabaugh Why did you change "number of walk" to "length of a walk"? Was there some indication from the OP that "length" was intended>

Comment: @bof It seemed to me that "number of steps in a walk" was intended, as there can be more than $n-1$ different paths from $i$ to $j$.

Comment: @DannyRorabaugh Yes, what I mean is number of steps in a walk. sorry for any confusion.